# How do I solve old selected is not working in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

I have a "select" and I need to keep selected the "option" after a request.
But after send a request the old value is not retrieved.
I'm using laravel 7.

The code is:

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option value="">Select an option...</option>
@foreach($sites as $s)
    <option value="{{ $s->id }}" {{ old('select1') == $s->id ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{$s->nome </option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ->with() function in your controller after the redirect:

```
return redirect('Your redirection')->with('select1', $request->select1);
```

Then replace {{ old('select1') == $s->id ? 'selected' : '' }} with:

```
@if(Session::get('select1') == $s->id) selected @endif
```

The option should look like

```
<option value="{{ $s->id }}" @if(Session::get('select1') == $s->id) selected @endif>{{$s->nome}} </option>
```